# Querying Data and Grouping by Day with Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I run a website that stores images and users get a hotlink.

I want to be able to query records made in the last 7 days in the table containing the uploaded image data, extract the `created_at` column only, and compile the data into an array, similar to making an archive list for a blog.

I would like for the results to be presented like:

```
[
    'Sunday' => 5,
    'Monday' => 45,
    'Tuesday' => 452,
    ...
]
```

Where each number represents the number of records created on each day. As long as I can output an array like that, I can handle the Javascript side easily.

Anybody have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
<?php

class Admin
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
    }
    public static function uploadsGraph()
    {
        $date       = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $uploads    = Upload::select('created_at')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek())->get();

        foreach($uploads as $date)
        {
            echo $date->created_at . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's another version I tried, but that didn't work out well.

```
class Admin
{
    public static function uploadsGraph()
    {
        $date           = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $uploadsByDay   = DB::table('uploads')
                            ->select(DB::raw('
                                YEAR(created_at) year,
                                MONTH(created_at) month,
                                MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name
                            '))
                            ->groupBy('year')
                            ->groupBy('month')
                            ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
                            ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
                            ->get();
        dd($uploadsByDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Have you written any code? We don't create you're code.

Comment: Are you asking about how to query the data, or how to make the graph?

Comment: @Arjan96s Sorry about that, I've included the code I've currently tried.

Comment: @watcher I'd like to just query the data. The javascript part I can figure out myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming that the number next to each day of the week represents the *number of records made on that day*, with the entire dataset you want to query ranging only over the last 7 days.

The idea here is to select the count of items that were created on the same day (ignoring completely the timestamp portion of the `created_at` column), so we can use `DB::raw` inside of a `select()` call to aggregate all of the entries that were created on a specific day and then restrict that dataset to only those created in the last week.  Something like this ought to work:

```
$data = Upload::select([
      // This aggregates the data and makes available a 'count' attribute
      DB::raw('count(id) as `count`'), 
      // This throws away the timestamp portion of the date
      DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as day')
    // Group these records according to that day
    ])->groupBy('day')
    // And restrict these results to only those created in the last week
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1))
    ->get()
;

$output = [];
foreach($data as $entry) {
    $output[$entry->day] = $entry->count;
}

print_r($output);
```

Also note that I assumed this to be a 'rolling' week, where if *today* happens to be a *Thursday*, then the first date in the dataset will be the previous *Thursday*.  It will not start on the most recent *Sunday*, if that is what you need. If it is, you can change the `-where()` condition to something like this:

```
...
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::parse('last sunday'))
...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DB::table("clicks")

->select("id" ,DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as total_click"))

    ->orderBy('created_at')

    ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))

    ->get();
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  You are grouping on `MONTH()`, but you don't include that value in the SELECT.  Does this work?